# Checkout ajax steps tracked with GTM ecommerce enhanced and dataLayer push

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, funnelweb

I'm wondering on how to tracks checkout and checkout steps events on google analytics.

I've a checkout in a single page and each steps is called via ajax requests, so I've already add the "dataLayer.push" functionality for each steps, bringing of course the step number in it.

Now I cannot catch anything on the funnel shown up on google analytics.

The funnel I'm talking about is the "Checkout Behavior Analysis" inside the Conversion -> Ecommerce -> Shopping Analysis.

The ecommerce code I'm using is the GTM one by pushing on dataLayer the checkout event when I'm loading the checkout page, and the checkoutOption event for each checkout ajax step. 
Once those events are pushed to the dataLayer on GTM I've set up the tag activator on the events to pass the information to google analytics with the universal analytics tag with event feature (not a pageview).

The codes for ajax events I'm pushing are the following.

Checkout Start:

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkout",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 1, "option": ""},
            "products": self.datas["checkout_items"]
        }
     }
});
```

Checkout Billing  Address

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkoutOption",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 2, "option": ""}
        }
    }
});
```

Checkout Shipping Address

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkoutOption",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 3, "option": ""}
        }
    }
});
```

Checkout Shipping Method

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkoutOption",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 4, "option": self.datas["shipping_method"] }
        }
    }
});
```

Checkout Payment Method

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkoutOption",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 5, "option": self.datas["payment_method"] }
        }
    }
});
```

Checkout Coupon

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkoutOption",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 6, "option": self.datas["couponcode"] }
        }
    }
});
```

Checkout Place Order

```
dataLayer.push({
    "event": "checkoutOption",
    "ecommerce": {
        "checkout_option": {
            "actionField": {"step": 7, "option": "" }
        }
    }
});
```

I've read all the enhanced guides like:

- https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide
- https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Is there something more I'm missing?

Best.
Francesco.

Comment: Have you configured your GTM tags to read ecommerce object from the dataLayer?

Comment: And have you included a custom event in your push ? An event is necessary so your tags are aware of changed data (and of course you need to trigger your tag on each step).

Comment: @nyuen that could be what I'm missing. I mean I've configured on GTM the tag "UA event" to be triggered on the "checkout" and the "checkoutOption" events. Those events are tracked on GA but the funnel is not gonna filled up with trackings.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the ecommerce code you are using? Also, where in GA are you checking for this "funnel"?

Comment: Done! Thank you @nyuen, hope to understand and reply correctly.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using?

Comment: @nyuen I've add the ajax push events to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have configured your tag (whether it's a pageview or event) to read in the dataLayer object whenever you have a checkout event. You would need to check the `Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features` and also the `Use Data Layer` under the Advanced Settings.

**Edit:**
The `checkout_option` field is only used when you need to provide supplemental information to a checkout step, for example if you want to add a payment method to the payment page.

Each checkout step in your checkout funnel needs to be added like this:

```
// Step 1
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'checkout start',
   'ecommerce': {
      'checkout': {
         'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Visa'},
         'products': // .... products
    }
}

// Step 2
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'checkout billing',
   'ecommerce': {
      'checkout': {
         'actionField': {'step': 2},
         'products': // .... products
    }
}
```

etc.

So you aren't actually sending any information for your steps with what you currently have.

Comment: Hi @nyuen the tag (event) is already set up to use enhanced ecomm with the data layer.

Comment: if you inspect the collect hit in the dev console (or with GA Debugger add-on for Chrome), are you able to see the Ecomm data associated in your event?

Comment: Hi @nyuen, sorry for the delay. I've been on away for a while. The events checkout and checkoutOptions are triggered and they are activating the tags. Infact I had the events tracked on google analytics, but they do not fill the ecommerce funnel. And I don't understand what I am missing..

Comment: Are you able to share your site to help troubleshoot?

Comment: You no longer need to append products data after the first step.