# Enhanced E-commerce Checkout Behavior Report

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm using `Google Tag Manager` tag to push checkout data to `Universal Analytics`.

*Tag*

- Tag Type: `Universal Analytics`
- Track Type: `Event`
- Category: `Ecommerce`
- Action: `Checkout`
- Enhanced E-commerce: `true`
- Data Layer: `true`
- Fire On: `Checkout`

*Trigger*

- Name: `Checkout`
- Event: `Custom Event`
- Fire On: `checkout`

*JavaScript*

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout',
  'ecommerce': {
    'checkout': {
      'actionField': { 'step': step, 'option': option }
    }
  }
});
```

Chrome Tag Assistant extension reports show that all values are passed to `Universal Analytics` `collect` action.

In `Behavior > Events > Top Events` I can see that events were properly registered by `UA`:

[image: Events]

Unfortunately `Conversions > E-commerce > Shopping Analysis > Checkout Behavior` doesn't show any data... my *question* is: "Why ?"

Comment: The solution to this is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703878/checkout-ajax-steps-tracked-with-gtm-ecommerce-enhanced-and-datalayer-push/37749704#37749704. You need to send the e-commerce product data along with other data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing product data in your dataLayer push
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkoutstep (edited)